# simple rest data provider won't accept Odata data

Tags: odata, react-admin

So the API I am using is using ODATA (https://www.odata.org/). As a result this is what it looks like when it's returned

```

```
{"@odata.context":"http://localhost:5001/api/$metadata#apemp",
"value":[
{"EmpID":1,
"Abbr":"Admin",
"BadgeNo":null,
"ColorRef":0,
"ContactMethodID":null,
"DateHired":"2018-05-25T16:42:57-05:00"}
```

]```

our data provider looks like this

```
import { stringify } from 'query-string';
import {
   fetchUtils,
   GET_LIST,
   GET_ONE,
   GET_MANY,
   GET_MANY_REFERENCE,
   CREATE,
   UPDATE,
   UPDATE_MANY,
   DELETE,
   DELETE_MANY
} from 'react-admin';

...
   const convertHTTPResponse = (response, type, resource, params) => {
      const { headers, json } = response;
      switch (type) {
         case GET_LIST:
            return { data: json };
         case GET_MANY_REFERENCE:
            if (!headers.has('content-range')) {
               throw new Error(
                  'The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response. The simple REST data provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare Content-Range in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?'
               );
            }
            return {
               data: json,
               total: parseInt(
                  headers
                     .get('content-range')
                     .split('/')
                     .pop(),
                  10
               )
            };
         case CREATE:
            return { data: { ...params.data, id: json.id } };
         default:
            return { data: json };
      }
   };

   return (type, resource, params) => {
      // simple-rest doesn't handle filters on UPDATE route, so we fallback to calling UPDATE n times instead
      if (type === UPDATE_MANY) {
         return Promise.all(
            params.ids.map(id =>
               httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${id}`, {
                  method: 'PUT',
                  body: JSON.stringify(params.data)
               })
            )
         ).then(responses => ({
            data: responses.map(response => response.json)
         }));
      }
      // simple-rest doesn't handle filters on DELETE route, so we fallback to calling DELETE n times instead
      if (type === DELETE_MANY) {
         return Promise.all(
            params.ids.map(id =>
               httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${id}`, {
                  method: 'DELETE'
               })
            )
         ).then(responses => ({
            data: responses.map(response => response.json)
         }));
      }

      const { url, options } = convertDataRequestToHTTP(type, resource, params);
      return httpClient(url, options).then(response =>
         convertHTTPResponse(response, type, resource, params)
      );
   };
};
```

so right now when I point that data provider to api endpoints it doesn't look the way the code is formatted.
 I get the error

"The response to 'GET_LIST' must be like { data : [...] }, but the received data is not an array. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'GET_LIST'"

I have used this dataprovider extensively with our previous API which returned data slightly differently.

since odata returns an object with the context and url as the items and the value with an array as the second item it doesn't work.

I really just need the array but don't know what I should be writing to get that.

Answer (score 0):

I am also implementing DataProvider for OData and what you need to do is that you have to "wrap" your response data stored in `value` with `data` object.

But the array is in `value` prop and you can't just assert `return { data: json };` like you do, because it expects object like {data: [0: {prop1: "hello", prop2: "world"}, 1: { ... }]} and you return this:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:5001/api/$metadata#apemp",
  "value":[
     {
       "EmpID":1,
       "Abbr":"Admin",
       "BadgeNo":null,
       "ColorRef":0,
       "ContactMethodID":null,
       "DateHired":"2018-05-25T16:42:57-05:00"
     }
  ]
}
```

So what you need to do is to assign value prop of response json, eg:

```
return { data: json.value };
```

So its actually pretty easy to fix